# Opengl Airplane Camera

Tags: opengl, c++, glm

I am making a game in opengl and am trying to get a camera to follow an airplane. How can I get the camera to match the roll, pitch, and yaw of the plane? I am using glm as my math library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to **match** the camera with the plane, all you have to do is use same transformation data as you do for your plane, to generate a view matrix for your camera.

But here's a catch, though. Camera positioning works in reverse for rasterization, so you need to invert your plane position to use it as a basis for camera transformation matrix.

```
//I suggest using quaternion for rotations (glm::quat), but for now
//let's consider to use Euler angles, as they are stated in the question
glm::vec3 plane_rotation_euler;
glm::vec3 plane_position;
//Presumingly, this is how you do plane transformation
glm::mat4 plane_world_transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
plane_world_transform =
    glm::translate(plane_world_transform, plane_position);
plane_world_transform =
    glm::rotate(plane_world_transform, plane_rotation_euler.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
plane_world_transform =
    glm::rotate(plane_world_transform, plane_rotation_euler.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
plane_world_transform =
    glm::rotate(plane_world_transform, plane_rotation_euler.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));

//Then this is how you calculate camera view transformation matrix
glm::mat4 view_transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
view_transform =
    glm::translate(view_transform , -plane_position);//Note the inversion
view_transform =
    glm::rotate(view_transform , plane_rotation_euler.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
view_transform  =
    glm::rotate(view_transform , plane_rotation_euler.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
view_transform =
    glm::rotate(view_transform , plane_rotation_euler.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```